# Difference between IISRESET and IIS Stop-Start command

Tags: windows, batch-file, iis, command-line, command

Is there any difference between commands `iisreset` and `iisreset /stop` followed by `iisreset /start` ?

Comment: Presumably `iisreset` command has the default action of stopping the service, then starting it. The `/stop` and `/start` switches just do one or the other.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Take IISReset as a suite of commands that helps you manage IIS start / stop etc.

This means you need to specify the option (`/switch`) what you want to do to carry out any operation.

Default behavior OR default switch is `/restart` with `iisreset` so you do not need to run the command twice with `/start` and `/stop`.

Hope this clarifies your question. For reference the output of `iisreset /?` is:

> ```
> IISRESET.EXE (c) Microsoft Corp. 1998-2005
>
> Usage:
> iisreset [computername]
>
>     /RESTART            Stop and then restart all Internet services.
>     /START              Start all Internet services.
>     /STOP               Stop all Internet services.
>     /REBOOT             Reboot the computer.
>     /REBOOTONERROR      Reboot the computer if an error occurs when starting,
>                         stopping, or restarting Internet services.
>     /NOFORCE            Do not forcefully terminate Internet services if
>                         attempting to stop them gracefully fails.
>     /TIMEOUT:val        Specify the timeout value ( in seconds ) to wait for
>                         a successful stop of Internet services. On expiration
>                         of this timeout the computer can be rebooted if
>                         the /REBOOTONERROR parameter is specified.
>                         The default value is 20s for restart, 60s for stop,
>                         and 0s for reboot.
>     /STATUS             Display the status of all Internet services.
>     /ENABLE             Enable restarting of Internet Services
>                         on the local system.
>     /DISABLE            Disable restarting of Internet Services
>                         on the local system.
> ```

Comment: @Baljeet..I was under the impression that there might be any hidden difference between these two commands, but I think thats not the case.

Comment: @Baljeetsingh, What's the difference between `iisreset` vs `net stop w3svc`/`net start w3svc`?

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry, I am not quite sure on that .

Comment: @Baljeetsingh: there is minor different. If you perform IISreset rather then stop and start. It is not realizing memory on server. In my daily activity we need to follow the process with stop and start because if your server utilize 80 to 92% memory then you need to wait until your memory utilization graph goes down. that time you need to perform -stop and-start. Some time we need to wait more than 10min for releasing memory.

Answer (score 30):

The following was tested for IIS 8.5 and Windows 8.1.

As of IIS 7, Windows [recommends restarting IIS via `net stop/start`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732317%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Via the command prompt (**as Administrator**):

```
> net stop WAS
> net start W3SVC
```

`net stop WAS` will stop `W3SVC` as well. Then when starting, `net start W3SVC` will start `WAS` as a dependency.

Comment: you should add answer that explains more details on the how they are different , alternate commands doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is the simplest way. i do not think it needed to be explain.

Comment: @jewelhuq, First line works but `net stop iisadmin` gives me "The service name is invalid." Is is sufficient to only reset `w3svc` ? What's the difference between `restting `w3svc` and running `iisreset`?

Comment: @Pacerier read here its well explained http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sudeepg/archive/2009/02/14/windows-2008-and-iisreset-exe.aspx and this as well https://jnjnboo.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/do-not-use-iisreset-in-windows-2008-alternatives-listed/ .. happy learning

Comment: @Baljeetsingh, Good link, but after reading it: What's the point of resetting `IISAdmin`? Resetting only `w3svc` seems to work fine.

Comment: @Pacerier, the point of restarting IISAdmin is that sudeepg is duplicating the button functions in IIS manager: "Open IIS Manager and then select the server node. In the right side pane, you will have an option to restart IIS."

Answer (score 10):

I know this is quite an old post, but I would like to point out the following for people who will read it in the future:
As per MS:

> Do not use the IISReset.exe tool to restart the IIS services. Instead,
> use the NET STOP and NET START commands. For example, to stop and
> start the World Wide Web Publishing Service, run the following
> commands:
>
> - NET STOP iisadmin /y
> - NET START w3svc
>
> There are two benefits to using the NET STOP/NET START commands to
> restart the IIS Services as opposed to using the IISReset.exe tool.
> First, it is possible for IIS configuration changes that are in the
> process of being saved when the IISReset.exe command is run to be
> lost. Second, using IISReset.exe can make it difficult to identify
> which dependent service or services failed to stop when this problem
> occurs. Using the NET STOP commands to stop each individual dependent
> service will allow you to identify which service fails to stop, so you
> can then troubleshoot its failure accordingly.

KB:https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/969864/using-iisreset-exe-to-restart-internet-information-services-iis-result