# gcAllowVeryLargeObjects not working in WCF Service

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, out-of-memory, config

In my C# WCF Service gcAllowVeryLargeObjects apparently isn't working.
In web.config I set

```
<runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

The machine is x64 with 32 GB RAM. Project built with AnyCPU, "Prefer 32-bit" is unchecked.
The simple code in the service to test the issue:

```
    public string Test(int a)
    {
        if(a == 0)
        {
            return $"Is64BitProcess: {Environment.Is64BitProcess}";
        }
        else if(a == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                int[] arr = new int[13805 * 55223];
                return "OK";
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                return exc.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
            return "nothing";
    }
```

on a==0, Is64BitProcess says 'true'

on a==1, I get an OutOfMemoryException: array dimensions exceeded supported range

The same code in a Windows Forms Application works fine, there is "OK" with gcAllow...="true" and OutOfMemory without it - as expected.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you host in IIS? You might have to make that config change for the process the app domain is hosted in. Only setting it for the app pool is not enough.

Comment: Yes its hosted in IIS. What do you mean - the config change I posted above is in the web.config of the wcf service. The app pool was not changed.

Comment: For the sake of testing, can you make that change in your machine.config; `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version you run on]\Config\machine.config` but do make a backup of that file because if you screw it up not much will work on your box. After you made the change restart iis ([iisreset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084561/difference-between-iisreset-and-iis-stop-start-command/29345630) should do) and then see if your code works in the website.

Comment: It works!! But is this the best practice, to manipulate a .NET Framework config file?

Comment: No, it is not. I'm looking for a place where you can add this so it only affects Inetinfo.exe. If you revert your machine.config change and then make the change in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config to see if that works (don't forget to iisreset after all changes)

Comment: The same change in applicationHost.config leads to not startable IIS: "Restart attempt failed. The IIS Admin Service or the World Wide Web Publishing Service, or a service dependent on them failed to start.  The service, or dependent services, may had an error during its startup or may be disabled."

Comment: Ouch! We broke it. That is unexpected. Sorry about that. Revert that change for now. I expect there should be another config somewhere that covers the actual host process. I doubt it is inetinfo.exe itself.

Comment: I wonder if I'm the only or the first one that ever attempts to use large arrays in an iis hosted service? There have to be more people encountering the same problem, I assumed...

Comment: Is there really no solution for this problem other than manipulating the .NET machine.config ?